# Target custom attributes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a slider (Slick Slider) and I am trying to target individual slides.

Here is an example of the things it spits into the divs.

```
<div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide01"></div>
<div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide02"></div>
```

I want to target each div using jQuery so I can add a class to it. I think the attribute I want to target is `aria-describedby`

I've tried doing this:

`jQuery("[aria-describedby='slick-slide01']").addClass("newClass");` but it doesn't seem to work.

I can't use nth child selectors because I have Slick set to infinite loop and nth child on this doesn't always select the right div. What can I try next?

Comment: Your code works just fine.

Comment: ah sorry, i think i figured it out. my addclass jquery was loading before the slick was initialized so it had nothing to attach to. thanks for confirming

Comment: There's a potential race like condition you may be hitting.
I'm not familiar with slick slider, but, if you're executing your code (that should work by the looks of it) before slick slider has had time to create/update the DOM with the info you're using it may appear your code is wrong but maybe just executed too soon.

Comment: @subhaze that is exactly it! thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, there is no problem with your code. You just have both divs empty, so it just looks like there is no change...

```js
jQuery("[aria-describedby='slick-slide01']").addClass("newClass");
```

```css
.newClass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide01">AAA</div>
<div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide02">AAA</div>
```

Comment: cool thanks, my addclass jquery was loading before the slick was initialized so it had nothing to attach to

Comment: If there is no problem with the code, you should not make an answer about it, simple just make a comment and close it as `problem can no longer be reproduced `

Comment: @cup_of I'm not sure why you voted to close it, since you can just remove the question, since there was no real problem according to your code.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I cant delete it because someone gave an answer